# Text box show next value if find zero(0) value vba excel

Tags: vba

```
For i = 1 To 20


If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Val(Me.TextBox13) Then
cn = cn + 1

Me("txtItem" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)

Me("Qty" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)

Me("Price" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)

Me("Total" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)

End If

Next i
```

This code does work properly, but I want `sheet1.cells(i,3)` means Quantity Column is any row is 0 then textbox result next value. All the time text box shows value without zero (0) value.

Userform Search and result

[image]

My worksheet (Sheet1)

[image]

Comment: This statement is unclear: "_but I want sheet1.cells(i,3) means Quantity Column is any row is 0 then textbox result next value._"

Comment: when i press search button then sheet1,cells(i,3) = column(qty) any rows value is zero then textbox(Item, Qty, Price, Total) show the result next value. It always ignore Zero (0) value. As example: In textbox13 is 1101 and press search button then the result is show the textbox(Item, Qty, Price, Total) > ban, 10, 10, 100 and gan, 10, 20, 200.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the qty column value is not 0 first and populate the controls with value if true:

```
For i = 1 To 20
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Val(Me.TextBox13) Then
                
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) <> 0 Then 'add in this line to check value of Qty column
            cn = cn + 1
            
            Me("txtItem" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            Me("Qty" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
            Me("Price" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
            Me("Total" & cn) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
        End If 'add in this line
    End If
Next i
```